# Looping through properties depending on the source in a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to loop through a set of data and, depending on which index I'm on, loop through a different set of data.

This should hopefully explain my goal

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set DEVICE_LIST="android-19" "android-18" "android-17"
set android-19="1" "2" "3"
set android-18="4" "5" "6"
set android-17="7" "8" "9"

for %%N in ( %DEVICE_LIST% ) do (
    echo %%N

    for %%A in ( %android-19% ) do (
        echo %%A
    )
)
```

So in that code block, the output is

```
"android-19"
"1"
"2"
"3"
"android-18"
"1"
"2"
"3"
"android-17"
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

But what would like to do is replace %android-19% with the name or index of the device, so the output is actually

```
"android-19"
"1"
"2"
"3"
"android-18"
"4"
"5"
"6"
"android-17"
"7"
"8"
"9"
```

I initially tried replacing %android-19% with %%%N% but obviously that won't work, but should give you the idea of what I'm going for.

Is it possible to do something like this, or something that would produce the same results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so posting this question gave me a load of possible links to related questions which actually helped me figure it out.

It was just a case of using the right combination of ! and % in the second for loop.

```
for %%N in ( %DEVICE_LIST% ) do (
    echo %%N

        for %%A in (  !%%~N! ) do (
            echo %%A
        )
)
```

Comment: What makes you think that sachadee?  It seems to be working fine as shown above (running Windows 7).

Comment: If your `DEVICE_LIST` is setted with `"` like in your exemple : set `DEVICE_LIST="android-19" "android-18" "android-17"`. The `%%N` will be `"android-19"` and that will not work in `!%%N!`without removing the `"` with `!%%~N!`.

Comment: Ah, I see. In my final code I actually removed the quotes from the list entries, which is why it works for me.  Answer updated to reflect the question though.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

set DEVICE_LIST="android-19" "android-18" "android-17"
set android-19="1" "2" "3"
set android-18="4" "5" "6"
set android-17="7" "8" "9"

for %%N in ( %DEVICE_LIST% ) do (
    echo %%N

    for /f "delims=" %%W in ('call echo(%%%%~N%%') do (
        for %%A in (%%W) do (
            echo %%A
    )
    )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

worked quite happily for me.